# Asp.Net MVC 5 или Web Api 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Я совсем запутался... 
Asp.Net MVC - создание веб-приложений, Web Api - сервисов. Не могли бы вы объяснить для каких задач пишутся сервисы, а для каких веб приложения? Насколько я понимаю, если у нас клиент планируется не только веб, но еще, например, WPF-приложение, мобильное, то выбор должен пасть в сторону сервисов.

Конкретно для моего случая: имеется некое десктопное приложение еще на WinWorms. Хочется его перевести в веб. И встает логичный вопрос что использовать: Asp.Net Web Api + AngularJs или Asp.Net MVC?

Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Бакэнд для AngularJs можно написать хоть на ASP.NET MVC, хоть на Asp.Net Web Api, хоть на WCF (да, WCF тоже умеет делать REST-сервисы). Основная разница между ними в следующем:

ASP.NET MVC подходит для генерации страниц на стороне сервера (но не мешает работать и клиентским фреймворкам). Выбрав связку Angular.js + Web Api, вы навсегда ограничите себя исключительно клиентской генерацией страниц, приобретя заодно возможные проблемы с индексацией поисковиками. Взамен - у вашего сайта автоматически появится API, которое можно сделать публичным.

Думаю, начать надо с выяснения ответов на следующие вопросы:

1. Сколько человек будут работать над проектом и какие технологии им знакомы?
2. Насколько само ваше веб-приложение укладывается в концепцию HTTP? Оно будет состоять из набора отдельных динамически генерируемых страниц или из одной (или нескольких) страниц, содержащих формы, контролы и экраны?

   Пример приложения первого вида - Википедия. Пример приложения второго вида - Gmail.

   2а. Предполагается ли, что страница никогда не будет обновляться полностью?

   2б. Сможет ли пользователь открыть одновременно 2 части вашего приложения в одной вкладке? (+ ко второму виду)

   2в. Понадобится ли пользователю делиться ссылкой с другими или ставить ссылку в закладки? (+ к первому виду)
3. Нужно ли вам публичное API?